# ClassCastException writing a Gephi plugin

Tags: java, gephi

I am trying to write a plugin for Gephi and get the following error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.gephi.graph.impl.GraphStore$NodeIterableWrapper cannot be cast to org.gephi.graph.api.Node at org.............execute(.....java:92)
```

The code in which the error occurred:

```
Node[] nodes = graph.getNodes().toArray();
for (Node n: nodes){
    .....
    List<Node> neighborNodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    for(Node m: nodes){
        NodeIterable iter = graph.getNeighbors(m);
        neighborNodes.add((Node) iter);
```

The last line causes the error. Is it possible via `NodeIterable` to insert the neighbors as nodes in the list `neighborNodes` without this cast? I'm new to writing Java plugins.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this javadoc](https://gephi.org/gephi/0.9.0/apidocs/org/gephi/graph/api/NodeIterable.html), `NodeIterable` is an `Iterable` of `Node`s.

So you probably should use a loop:

```
NodeIterable iter = graph.getNeighbors(m);
for (Node n: iter) {
    neighborNodes.add(n);
}
```

or `addAll` and [`toCollection`](https://gephi.org/gephi/0.9.0/apidocs/org/gephi/graph/api/NodeIterable.html#toCollection--):

```
NodeIterable iter = graph.getNeighbors(m);
neighborNodes.addAll(iter.toCollection());
```